# htaccess multiple domain, force specific domain and its paths to www and exclude a path but redirect excluded path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How to force a specific domain name and all its path to www except a specific path but redirect that specific path to another domain. So what I want is to force 
`en.one` and all its paths to `www.en.one` except `en.one/admin`. but on top of that I want the excluded `en.one/admin` to go to another domain `http://www.en.me`.

So far I have managed to exclude `en.one/admin` but I still have failed to redirect `en.one/admin` to `http://www.en.me`.
My code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.one$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/admin //This excludes the /admin
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.en.one/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Note**: this is a multisite and multiple domains are managed by this single `.htaccess` file so solution is really important to be domain specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Christophe for helping me find a solution. You can check out our conversation as comments within Christophe's answer. The solution was to repeat the HTTP_HOST condition again. So in the end my `.htaccess` looked like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_host} ^en.one$     
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin     
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.en.one/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_host} ^en.one$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin         
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.en.me/ [R=301,L]
```

I am sure there could be better solutions but this works for me just as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to concat few conditions

```
## Not www include
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+) [NC]
## Not admin directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/ [NC]
## then rewrite to www.
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
## And then redirect your admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.en.me/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I tried your solution but got Internal Server Error when accessing `/admin` 
I tried your solution with a small change as I mentioned in my post that this .htacces file is very domain sensitive and solution needs to be very domain specific. 
I tried the following steps.
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_host} ^en.one$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.en.one/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.en.me/$1 [R=301, L]`

Comment: The error message displayed was  `RewriteRule: bad flag delimeters`

Comment: First of all, don't forget to turn the engine on with 'RewriteEngine on' at the very top of the file.

Comment: Yes I did that, but because of character limit I didn't include it.

Comment: I can see you forget the 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d' line btw 1st cond and request_uri cond

Comment: I added that line and still receiving the same error.

Comment: When you access `/admin` what do you get ??

Comment: Anyway, the flags [NC] are not so important anfd can be deleted. As the error seems to come from them, delete the [NC] flags but not the [R=301,L]

Comment: I got a 404 with /admin
But you may change 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/' by RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin

Comment: No I cant access the domain anymore. I get 500 error on both cases

Comment: Test the 2 conditions seperatly to know if both are returning a 500

Comment: The first condition works. It works until the first RewriteRule. The statements below the first RewriteRule creates 500 error.

Comment: The first condition however does not exclude the `/admin`

Comment: Ok, the 500 comes from your code, you left a space in [R=301, L] btw the 301 and the comma...

Comment: Indeed the 500 comes from the space, although, since this being a multisite the `/admin` redirection is picked up by other domain as well and not specific only to `en.one`.

Comment: I tried a dirty solution and it seems to work, after the RewriteRule I added 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_host} ^en.one$` again and `/admin` seems to be picked up by only `en.one` which is what I wanted but would like to know your thoughts.

Comment: You got it, It's not that dirty, just another condition, it's ok for me !

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will post a new answer referencing to your answer.