# How do I redirect a path to another path on another domain for only a given domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, litespeed

I would like to redirect myname.me/a-path to blog.myname.com/this-path/. The directory that serves myname.me also serves myname.com. I do not want myname.com/a-path to redirect to blog.myname.com/this-path/.

I have tried several things with mod_rewrite and most recently have tried the following.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myname\.me\$
RewriteRule a-path https://blog.myname.com/this-path/  [L,R=301]
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myname\.me\$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/a-path
RewriteRule https://blog.myname.com/this-path/  [L,R=301]
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myname.me$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/a-path         
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://blog.myname.com/this-path/  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This post tried to achieve a similar result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056085/htaccess-multiple-domain-force-specific-domain-and-its-paths-to-www-and-exclude

Answer (score 0):

This is how I redirect to a subdomain within the same host.

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^\/a-path\/$ https://blog.myname.com/this-path/ [L]
```